# Multicolored placeholder text

Tags: html, css

I need to create an HTML text input element that features multicolored placeholder text. All of the text should be gray except, but a closing asterisk should be red, as in:

[image]

This strikes me as a seemingly simple task that is actually a lot more complicated because of how browsers restrict our ability to style native input elements.

I have heard of people using CSS to override native input styles so they can use custom fonts, etc., but is there away to have two special text styles (gray and red)? Or do I need to use an alternative (non-native) input?

Comment: There's no way to do this without a huge amount of hassle. (You'd have to use `span` element and hide them dynamically... or maybe put the asterisk in a background image if you can live with it being to the left of the word)

Comment: Please add code otherwise it is nearly impossible to help

Comment: You probably *could* use a little jQuery to inspect the form elements, looking for a value (such as class="required") and perhaps you might be able to assign properties, add tags, or whatever to do the necessary formatting.  If you're open to a little jQuery trickery to  handle that, I could try and draft up a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Pekka and michael. I'm open to any solution, including something based on JS and CSS, as long as it is reusable and not too complex!

Comment: Placeholder text is not a replacement for proper labels.

Comment: cimmanon, what do you see as the disadvantage of using a placeholder instead of a label?

Comment: @hawkharris Refer to my answer for a wide supporting option. IE 8 and up support I believe, best of luck!

Comment: The 'disadvantage' is the explicit guidance given by the W3C:"[The `placeholder` attribute should not be used as an alternative to a `label`.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute)"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vmuJm/

The trick: address the placeholder text, add a "required" class to required inputs, and use the `:after` pseudo element to add an appropriately colored asterisk.

**[EDIT]** It looks like this is only working for Webkit browsers.

Comment: be careful because this won't work on most IE, but this is a good solution

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out--I didn't check for x-browser compatibility, but the OP should be able to code something that degrades gracefully.

Comment: I'm on Firefox 25.0.1 and do not see the asterisk at all in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I have a rather fun way to do this and seems to work great in all browsers.

(Works fine in IE 8+, chrome, and Firefox.)

What I am doing is using the spans I put inside of the label to act as the value text.

Here is the html structure,

```
<label><span class="title">Name<span class="symbol">*</span></span>
    <input type="text" />
</label>
```

The css,

```
label {
    position: relative;
}

label:hover span {
    display: none;
}

input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="text"]:active {
    z-index: 2;
}

label input[type="text"] {
    position: relative;
}

.title {
    color: gray;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 1px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.symbol {
    color: red;
}
```

Last here is the jQuery I wrote to not allow the span to hover over your input if the input is filled in.

```
$('input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
    if( $(this).val().length >= 1) {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VQMNy/3/) to play with.