# How to add multicolor placeholder text in React Native TextInput?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to add a red star at the end of my `TextInput` placeholder in **React Native**.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multicolored placeholder text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20667108/multicolored-placeholder-text)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71121181/how-to-add-red-asterisk-in-react-native-textinput-placeholder/71616686?answertab=createdasc#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20direct%20method%20to%20do%20this.What%20I%20did%20is%20add%20text%20with%20asterix%20in%20front%20of%20the%20TextInput%20and%20show%20hide%20conditionally%20when%20there%20is%20value%20in%20TextInput%20or%20not%2C

Answer (score 0):

You can use an :after selector and add content: "*" to it then you can give any color you want.

Something like this

```
p::after {
  content: "*";
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: This answer appears to by HTML -- the OP is asking about React Native. Is there a way to apply this answer to React Native?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a more elegant solution, I'd fake it with a background view for the `TextInput` that displays styled `Text` elements:

```
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState(null)
  const [isFocused, setFocused] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={{position: 'absolute'}}>
    <View style={{zIndex: -1, position: 'absolute'}}>
        {(text || isFocused) ? null : <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}><Text>Title</Text><Text style={{color: 'red'}}>*</Text></View>}
    </View>
      <TextInput value={text} onChangeText={t => setText(t)} style={{borderWidth: 1}} onFocus={() => setFocused(true)} onBlur={() => setFocused(false)}/>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```